# NoMethodError: undefined method `comments' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbaee1f8f00>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to fetch the followable items and the trying to fetch Posts of these users. Below is the code I am using

```
def dashboard
    @posts = []
    @Bposts = []
    @users = Follow.where('followable_type == ?',"User").where('follower_id == ?',current_user.id)
    @blogs = Follow.where('followable_type == ?',"Blog").where('follower_id == ?',current_user.id)
    @users.each do |user|
      @posts << Post.where('user_id == ?',user.followable_id).where('blog_id == ?',nil)
    end
    @blogs.each do |blog|
      @Bposts << Post.where('blog_id == ?',nil)
    end
    if @posts.count != 0
      @posts.each do |post|
        @comment = post.comments.build
      end
    end
    if @Bposts.count != 0
      @Bposts.each do |post|
        @comment = post.comments.build
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `comments' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbaee1f8f00>
```

You are getting this error because, you are calling `comments` on `<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation>` object, but you actually wanted to do this on a Post object.

Currently, your `@posts` is an array of `<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation>` so when you loop through `@posts`, each of the `post` is a `<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation>` which is causing this error when you call `post.comments.build` on it.

To fix the error, you have to change this:

```
@users.each do |user|
  @posts << Post.where('user_id == ?',user.followable_id).where('blog_id == ?',nil)
end
```

to:

```
@users.each do |user|
  @posts << Post.where('user_id == ?',user.followable_id).where('blog_id == ?',nil).first
end
```

This way, you will get an array of `post` objects in your `@posts` instance variable and then you can loop through them, get one `post` each time and call: `post.comments.build` for each `post`.

You need to make similar change for the `@Bposts` loop too. Make sure you call the `comment` method on a `Post` object, NOT a `ActiveRecord_Relation` object.

Comment: .first will only return first post of the user but I am trying to retreve all the posts of the users

Comment: yeah, but the way you did that, its possible to that way. If you want to do really that way, you will need another loop inside the `@posts.each do |post|` loop because then each of this post will be a `ActiveRecord_Relation ` object which also needs to be looped through.

Comment: is there any easy way to implement this functionality?